# Variance of mean square

Tags: statistics

$\bar{X}=\frac{\sum X_i}{n}$, what is the variance of mean square, 
$\mathrm{Var}(\bar{X}^2)$?

Is it $\sum\frac{\mathrm{Var}(x_i^2)}{n^2}$  (summation of $\mathrm{Var}(x_i^2)$ over $n^2$ )?

Comment: Consider formatting your question properly as it is unclear.

Comment: @user70454 I fixed your formatting, only. But the question is still very unclear. Can you clarify it?

Comment: I have revised the question, thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

The variance of mean has a simple formula when the random variables $X_i$ are uncorrelated: that is,  $E((X_i-\mu_i)(X_j-\mu_j))=0$ whenever $i\ne j$, where $\mu_i$ is the mean of $X_i$. Under this assumption, 
$$\operatorname{Var} \frac1n\sum X_i= \frac1{n^2} E\left(\sum (X_i-\mu_i)\right)^2 = \frac1{n^2} \sum E (X_i-\mu_i)^2= \frac1{n^2} \sum \operatorname{Var} X_i$$

However, it appears that your question is about the variance of  $\left(\frac1n\sum X_i\right)^2$, which by definition is
$$
\frac1{n^4} E\left(\left(\sum X_i\right)^2-E \left(\sum X_i\right)^2 \right)^2 \tag1
$$
The formula (1) does not seem to simplify much. It certainly cannot be expressed in terms of $\operatorname{Var}(X_i^2)$. Consider the special case when $X_i$ take only the values $\pm1$ . Then $\operatorname{Var}(X_i^2)=0$ for all $i$, while the sample means, and their squares, may have a nontrivial distribution.

Comment: See https://visit.randy.city/post/2020/variance-of-sample-mean-squared/